# UILabel does not show

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im trying to add a UILabel programaticly (ive done it with IB and it works). But I cant find out why it doesnt show up.. I've added a button programaticly that works just fine. I want the button to update the label with a random quote. Whats wrong?

.h-file:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *citatDatabas;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *helloButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *citatKnapp;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

- (void)helloButtonPressed;
- (IBAction)citatKnappPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

implementation:

```
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize helloButton, citatKnapp, label1;

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView]; 
citatDatabas = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"People ask me, would you rather be feared or loved, um easy, I want people to be afriad of how much they love me - Michael Scott" ],
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"You miss 100% of all the shoots you dont take - Wayne Greatsky - Michael Scott" ],
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"DONT PANIC - hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy" ],
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Give someone a mask and they'll show their true face - Oscar Wilde" ],
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Given enough time, hydrogen starts to wonder where it came from, and where it is going" ],
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"You have just begun reading the sentence you just finished reading" ],
                    nil];



    self.citatKnapp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.citatKnapp.frame = CGRectMake(98, 162, 124, 37);
    [self.citatKnapp setTitle:@"Tryck för citat" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.citatKnapp addTarget:self action:@selector(citatKnappPressed:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.citatKnapp.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [self.view addSubview:self.citatKnapp];

    self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 71, 200, 83)];

    self.label1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 71, 200, 83);
    self.label1.text = @"hej";
    self.label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.label1];


}

- (IBAction)citatKnappPressed:(id)sender{

    self.label1.text = [citatDatabas objectAtIndex:
                  (random() % [citatDatabas count])];
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a different `frame` on the UILabel to make sure that it’s not just being positioned incorrectly?

Comment: The label is an IBOutlet, so am I to assume you have created it in interface builder? If so try removing `self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 71, 200, 83)]`.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle no i added it programaticly, removed the IBOutlet, but now I understand what it does! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label is getting released, use `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;`

if you put a break point on any line after you alloc label1 you will see that label1 is nil

Comment: That wouldn't result in the label not being visible, because he's adding it to the view and a view always keeps strong references to it's subviews.

Comment: when using weak references it will get released immidiatly after this line: `self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 71, 200, 83)];` so it will already be nil when he is adding it to the view.

Comment: accutally this did fix it :O But i dont understand why/how?

Comment: a weak reference only lasts as long as something different is holding it strong. If you create an object and only put it into a weak variable it will not survive this line of code.

Comment: but when i created the same label in storyboard with IB, it says @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label; and that works? thats why i dont understand it i think

Comment: thats because its getting added to your view, as a subview, before its getting cleaned up, so your view has a strong handle to it. You could leave your label1 variable as a weak variable and alloc your label like this:
`UILabel* tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 71, 200, 83)];

label1 = tempLabel;`

Answer (score 0):

The reason in loadView, your view is not initialized. is it connected via XIB/StoryBoard?

if not,

just initialize your view as first line in your method adding label to it

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
```

then write your rest of ur code

Comment: it is initialized in IB storyBoard